# I deleted some of the NuGet files by mistake due to which my Visual Studio Code is now broken

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nuget

So I deleted some of the NuGet files by mistake. When I later put them back into the system from the trash, my visual studio code could not execute commands upon entering 'dotnet run'. It shows the following error. Any help?

The console error:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall packages from the package manager, then install them back? Or maybe rollback to working version from source control (if there is one)?

Comment: @SeM Can u do that in visual studio code?

Comment: I think so, sorry but I'm not experienced in VS code.

Comment: First of all specify the packages you deleted by accident so we can help you to re-install them. In VS code you can use command `dotnet add package <package name>`

Comment: on the nuget package they appear instaled? maybe try to delete nuget cache and restore them?

Comment: @Blue I think the package name is there in the error. Also, i tried doing `dotnet add package <name>` (i replaced <name>). It still shows the same error